# If $H$ is a Hilbert space, $U≤H$ is closed and $E≤U^⊥$ such that $x∈H$ with $x⊥_H E$ implies $x∈U$, then $U^⊥=\overline E^{\langle\;⋅\;,\;⋅\;\rangle}$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let

- $\left(H,\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle\right)$ be a separable Hilbert space
- $U$ be a closed subspace of $H$
- $E$ be a subspace of $$U^\perp:=\left\{x\in H:\langle x,u\rangle=0\text{ for all }u\in U\right\}$$

Suppose that we can show the following Lemma:

> Let $x\in H$ with $x\perp E$, i.e. $$\langle x,e\rangle=0\;\;\;\text{for all }e\in E\;.$$ Then, $x\in U$.

Why can we conclude that $U^\perp=\overline E^{\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: $E^\perp\subset U$ implies $U^\perp\supset \overline{E}=E^{\perp\perp}\supset U^\perp$.

Let's see what's going on here. First, if $X\subset Y\subset H$, then $X^\perp\supset Y^\perp$ just by definition. Applied to the subspaces in question we get $E^{\perp\perp}\supset U^\perp$.

Further, $E^{\perp\perp}$ is a closed subspace containing $E$ (once again easy to check using only the definition), so $E^{\perp\perp}\supset \overline E$. On the other hand, every $x\in E^{\perp\perp}$ can be decomposed as $x=y+z$ with $y\in \overline{E}$ and $z\in \overline {E}^\perp\cap E^{\perp\perp}$. As $\overline{E}^{\perp}\cap E^{\perp\perp}=\{0\}$ we conclude that $\overline{E}=E^{\perp\perp}$.

Finally, $U^\perp$ is a closed set containing $E$, hence $U^\perp\supset \overline{E}$.

Comment: Why is $\overline{E}^{\perp}\cap E^{\perp\perp}=\{0\}$?

Comment: We have $E^{\perp}=\overline{E}^\perp$ (being orthogonal to all elements in an approximating sequence implies being orthogonal to the limit since the inner product is continuous). Now, if $x\in E^\perp\cap E^{\perp\perp}$, then $\langle x,x\rangle=0$, hence $x=0$.

Comment: Let me try to figure out the necessary assumptions: We need that $E$ is a vector subspace (not only a subset and not necessary a sub-Hilbert space) of $H$ in order to show $E^{\perp\perp}=\overline E$. And we need that $U$ is a vector subspace of $H$ (together with $E\subseteq U^\perp$) in order to show $\overline E\subseteq U^\perp$. We cannot relax one of those assumptions. Right?

Comment: In addition to my question: I've assumed that $E\subseteq U^\perp$ **and** $E^\perp\subseteq U$. Are these assumptions redundant, i.e. can we drop one of them? I'm not sure, but I've noticed that they together imply $$\overline U=U^{\perp\perp}\subseteq E^\perp\subseteq U\subseteq\overline U\;,$$ i.e. $E^\perp=\overline U$.